# Range.Autofilter gives error 800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am writing an Excel AddIn, and have problems with the Range.Autofilter method.

Minimal code example of what does not work for me:

```
Excel.Worksheet currentWorksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
currentWorksheet.Cells.AutoFilter();
```

This code throws error 800A03EC for me.
I am using Excel 2013 and Visual Studio 2012, if that affects the answer.

Comment: Just google "excel autofilter error 1004", 179 thousand hits.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know where I should have taken the 1004 from, but ok. Most of the hits were different problems, but now I think the problems is my worksheet is separated into two tables.

Comment: The Excel error code is stored in the low 16-bits of the HResult value.  0x03EC == 1004.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that Range.AutoFilter() does not seem to work if the data is formatted as a table (or, in the code, is a ListObject). Instead, I got the intended result by doing

```
foreach (ListObject obj in currentWorksheet.ListObjects)
 {
            obj.ShowAutoFilter = true;
 }
```